# Computing the determinant of a $4\times4$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

> Compute the determinant of \begin{vmatrix} 2 & -1 & 1 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 & 2 & -2 \end{vmatrix}

**My try:**
$$\begin{vmatrix} 2 & -1 & 1 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 & 2 & -2 \end{vmatrix}_{R_2\rightarrow2R_2-R_1\\R_3\rightarrow R_3-R_1\\R_4\rightarrow2R_4+R_1}$$
$$\begin{vmatrix} 2 & -1 & 1 & 3 \\ 0 & 5 & -1 & -1 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 & -4 \\ 0 & 1 & 5 & -1 \end{vmatrix}$$
Now I took $$\begin{vmatrix} 5 & -1 & -1 \\ 2 & 0 & -4 \\ 1 & 5 & -1 \end{vmatrix}=92$$
But the answer is $46$. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When doing some operations on rows and columns of a matrix you have to be pretty careful: remember that the determinant is a *multilinear map in the rows and the columns* so it follows that

> Multiplying or dividing a row or a column by a scalar $\lambda$, multiplies or divides the determinant by the same scalar $\lambda$

So if $A$ is your initial matrix and $B$ is the matrix obtained by multiplying a column of $A$ by a scalar $\lambda$ you have that $$\det(B) = \lambda\det(A)$$
So in your case you've done $2$ multiplications by $2$ then the determinant of your final matrix will be $4$ times the determinant of the initial matrix. So you have that your determinant will be $$92/4\times 2 = 46$$

Obviously the times two is there for the Laplace expansion.

Comment: (96/4)*2 = 48 …

Comment: @current_user Yeah, just mistyped a LOT! ahah thanks

Comment: @DavideMorgante why did you multiply $\dfrac{92}{4}$ with $2$

Comment: As I said in the post is for the Laplace expansion: you're expanding your determinant on the first column so, with alternating signs, you multiply the determinant of the minors (that are found taking away the row and the column of a chosen element) by the element that identify the minor. In your case 3 out of 4 elements are zeros so the determinant of that minors is zero and the first one is 2 so the determinant has to be multiplied by 2

Answer (score 2):

Because you multiplied the first and the third rows by 2 while making the row operations, hence the determinant you found is 4 times bigger than the determinant of the original matrix. So the answer is $\frac{92*2}{4}$=46.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this question has been asked and answered many times, but I can't find it.

You can add or subtract a multiple of another row to a given row, without changing the value of the determinant, so $$R_1=R_1+4R_2$$
is perfectly OK.  When you multiply a row by $k$, you multiply the determinant by $k$.  When you do $$R_2=2R_2-R_1$$ you are really doing two operations.  First, you multiply row $2$ by $2$, then you subtract row $1$ from row $2$.  The effect of this is to multiply the determinant by $2$.

It's fine to do these operations, as long as you keep track of them, so you can adjust the value of the determinant at the end.

The second mistake you made is at the end.  Because of the $2$ in the $(1,1)$ position, you should have multiplied the $3\times3$ by $2$ giving $184$, which is $4$ times the true value.  This is because you performed that "row-doubling" operation twice.

Answer (score 1):

You multiplied two rows by two, so your answer (184) is 4 times greater than the actual determinant. [This](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/matrix-transformations/determinant-depth/v/linear-algebra-determinant-after-row-operations) video may help.